# Not able to create AVD with API 18 ( API 19 works fine )

Tags: android, eclipse

Previously I had API 19 and AVD creation works fine. I wanted to run against API 18.. So installed API 18 through SDK Manager. Restarted Eclipse.

Now, when I am selecting API 18; clicking on Ok doesnt do anything.. Nothing is printed on logs/console also.  Though ok button is enabled. [image]API 19 still works fine.

Attached are both screen shots.[image]

Comment: I did checked for Updates. No update found.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that "No system images installed for this target" which is for target 18... This error is shown there while creating AVD itself under CPU sub-header...